# How to get all the causes of an exception using core Java only?

Tags: java

I have an SQL exception stack trace to demonstrate this. I want to get all the lines which start with "Caused by:". I don't want to use any Apache APIs for this. How do I do it ?

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:489)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:553)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:254)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:528)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at source.DBUtils.getDBConnection(DBUtils.java:41)
    at source.Mups.main(Mups.java:42)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:439)
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:454)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:693)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:251)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1140)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:340)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:149)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:133)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:405)
    ... 13 more
```

I scanned the SQLException api docs quickly and tried to make some code for my catch section. I got only the first error. What is my mistake ?

```
catch (SQLException e) {
   ArrayList<String> errList = new ArrayList<String>();
   errList.add(e.getCause().toString());
   SQLException eNew = null;
   do{
      eNew = e.getNextException();
      if(eNew != null){
      Throwable th = eNew.getCause();
      errList.add(th.toString());
     }
    }while(eNew != null);

   for(String s : errList){
      System.out.println(s);
    }
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: The "cause" exception comes from `getCause`.

Comment: Note that `getNextException` is a method specific to SQLException.  I think it's intended more to handle the case where multiple exceptions need to be returned for a multi-part SQL query (but I don't recall the details).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to recursively look at causes. So, you've caught exception `e`, and you can get the cause of that as `e1 = e.getCause()`, but then the cause of `e1` could be found as `e2 = e1.getCause()`, and the cause of `e2` as `e3 = e2.getCause()`, et cetera.

This is how you can do it -

```
catch (SQLException e) {
  Throwable cause = e.getCause();
    while (cause != null) {
     System.out.println(cause);
     cause = cause.getCause();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the concept behind what I need. Thumbs up ! I'll add the simple code to your question, which worked for me.

Comment: The only thing that surprises me is this - When I try to connect to the database using TOAD, I get the exception ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout. But, the exceptions give me no such code. I tried looking at the get-error-code method and get-message and did not get the same codes. Just wondering how TOAD manages to get that.

Comment: Did you try to get the error code from the original SQLException, and not just the causes?

Answer (score 1):

```
for(Throwable t = e; t != null; t = t.getCause()) errList.add(t.toString());
```

Should do what you want. 
It is not likely to be very useful though. Unless you are looking for something specific, the only thing that has any interesting information is usually the original exception, that will be the last item in your list. Everything else is just noise.